# How to only list .png files that have been modified in Git

Tags: bash, git, cp

How would one go about only listing the png files that have been modified in the current branch on Git?

My goal is to copy those files to a different directory (I need to send an email).

Suppose I have:

```
$ git status
On branch update_assessment_pt1
Your branch is up-to-date with 'upstream/devel'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/analysis/hbepr1_plot.py
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/AxialPowerProfile.pdf
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/AxialProfile.pdf
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/CladDisp.pdf
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/FissionGas.pdf
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/FissionGas.png
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/InterGasPress.pdf
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/Mesh.pdf
    deleted:    assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/Power.pdf
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/Power.png
    new file:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/analysis/ifa431_plot.py
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431_bol_rod_power.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r1.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r2.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r3.png
```

How would I go about getting the following, so I can copy those files?

```
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/FissionGas.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/HbepR1/doc/figures/Power.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431_bol_rod_power.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r1.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r2.png
    modified:   assessment/LWR/validation/IFA_431/doc/figures/431r3.png
```

Comment: `git diff --diff-filter=M` with the right base and tip

Comment: @jthill I'm sorry, what do you mean by base and tip?

Comment: See @torek's answer, git actually defaults to the versions you want. base and tip are the two versions you want to compare, git's a little loose about terminology.  For instance, "indexed", "added", "staged", "cached" and "tracked" all generally mean the same thing, it's anything listed in the index, you pick your terms based on what potential use you want to evoke. I used "base" and "tip" just to evoke a branch's history, as torek suggests Git gets a huge amount of its power from its choice to keep content front and center and keep diffs as sometimes-very-useful derivations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git diff --cached --diff-filter=M --name-only` to obtain these file names.  Add `-- '*.png'` if needed to keep the list filtered to just `*.png` files—the command will list *any* `to be committed` file whose status is `M` (modified).

#### Things to know to keep this from just being a "use this magic command" answer

In text, you first called these *modified in the current branch*.  This phrase doesn't mean any one specific thing.  Fortunately you then went on to show `git status` output, where they were listed under `Changes to be committed`.

Git doesn't *store* diffs at all.  Git stores *snapshots*—whole files, intact, inside the main unit of storage, which is the commit.  That means that in order to see a *change*, you have to pick *two* commits: $old and $new.  Git will extract both, then compare them.  Whatever is different between commit $old and commit $new, Git will tell you about that.  The actual change can be any of a number of change-status-es:

- `A` means Added: the file is not in $old and is in $new.
- `M` means Modified: the file is different between $old and $new.  The difference could just be the *mode* of the file: executable, or not.
- `D` means Deleted: the file is in $old, but not in $new.
- `R`, `C`, `T`, and some other rare cases can also occur, though some of them may require extra flags to `git diff`: you won't see an `R` status unless you enable rename-detection, for instance.  (Rename detection defaults to *on* in the most modern Git versions, but *off* in older Git versions.)

Using `--name-status`, `git diff` will show you the file names and status letters, instead of showing an actual diff.  (Try this out to see.)  The `--diff-filter` argument lets you tell Git: *only tell me about files whose status meets the letters I pick.*

Note, by the way, that the special name `HEAD` always means *the current commit*.  It does not matter how you made this commit become the current commit, though one typical way is by using `git checkout`: you `git checkout` a commit by its hash ID, for instance, and that commit is now checked out and is the current commit.  Or, you `git checkout` a branch name, and the *tip* commit of that branch is now out and is the current commit.  There is always<sup>1</sup> a current commit, and you can name it by writing the name `HEAD` in all uppercase.<sup>2</sup>

All of the above talks about comparing *commits*, but there are two other places that files can exist, that are not commits.  Note that *both* of these places are temporary: they get wiped out by various operations, and once wiped out, *cannot* be recovered in Git: you have to copy from these temporary places, into actual commits, to make the files permanent.  Once the files are in commits, they're frozen for all time, and can be restored to useful form in the future for as long as the commit itself exists (which tends to be "forever", or as long as the repository exists).

These two places are:

- the *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area* or (rarely) the *cache*, and
- the *work-tree* or *working tree* or any of several variants on this name.

Files that are in the index *right now* are ready to be committed.  *Every* file that will be committed *is* in the index right now, even if the index copy matches the current (`HEAD`) commit copy.

You can, at any time, compare the `HEAD` commit to whatever is in the index right now.  One command that does this is `git diff --cached`.  For every file in `HEAD` and/or in the index, Git compares the two copies of the file.  If they are different, the file is modified.  If the index file exists but there is no such file in `HEAD`, the file is added.  If the file exists in `HEAD` but not in the index, the file is deleted.

You can also, at any time, compare `HEAD` to the work-tree, or the index to the work-tree.  The commands that do this are `git diff HEAD` and `git diff` (with no name).  Again, for every file on the left-hand side (`HEAD` or the index), and every file on the right-hand side (in the work-tree), Git compares the two copies of the file.

Last, note that `git status` runs *two* `git diff`s.  It does a quick `git diff --cached` to compare `HEAD` vs index.  Whatever is different here, `git status` lists that file as *to be committed*.  It also does a quick `git diff` (with no extra arguments except for `--name-only`) to compare index vs work-tree.  Whatever is different here, `git status` lists that file as *changes not staged for commit*.

You wanted to compare `HEAD` vs index, so you want `git diff --cached`.  You then wanted to list only those files that are `M`odified, so you can add `--diff-filter=M`.  You didn't want to see the actual differences—nor even the status letters; file names only please!—so you can add `--name-only`.  You also wanted only to list files whose name matches `*.png`, so add `-- '*.png'`—the quotes protect the `*` from the shell; we want *Git* to see the `*` so that Git can treat it as a *pathspec*—to get just those.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, this is really *almost always*.  There's a special state in which `HEAD` exists and contains a branch name, but the branch name itself *doesn't* exist.  This state mostly occurs when you create a new, totally-empty repository.  Git requires a branch name like `master` to identify some existing, valid commit hash ID.  There are no commits, so there are no valid hash IDs, so `master` itself is not allowed to exist.  Nonetheless, `HEAD` holds the *name* `master`, so that Git will *create* the `master` branch when you make the first commit.

<sup>2</sup>On Windows and MacOS, you can sometimes get away with using `head` (lowercase) instead of `HEAD` (all-uppercase).  This misbehaves if you start using `git worktree add`, so it's a bad habit to get into.  If you don't like typing `HEAD` in all capitals, consider using the symbol `@`, which is a synonym for `HEAD`.

Comment: Maybe you should publish on the web a git tutorial. Your explanation is excellent and enlightning.